# Call constructor of derived class from base class -> or how to do a proper Bestiary

Tags: c#, oop, derived-class

what I have is:

```
namespace Heroes.Classes
{
class Enemy
{
    private int HP;
    private int Attack;
    private int Defense;

    public string Name;

    Dice dice = new Dice();

    public enum Bestiary
    {
        Beasts,
        Undeads
    }

    public enum Beast
    {
        Wolf,
        Bear,
        Boar
    }

    public enum Undead
    {
        Skeleton,
        Ghost,
        Ghoul
    }

    public Enemy()
    {
    // here I want to call random CLASS which is derived from this 
    // base class -> that means I want here to create object 
    // Beasts() if Beasts is selected from enum Bestiary
    }

    public void EnemySwitch(Bestiary bestiary)
    {

        switch (bestiary)
        {
            case Bestiary.Beasts:
                // here I want to call constructor without any parameter -> which means a call random Beast/Method from class Beasts
                break;
            case Bestiary.Undeads:
                // here I want to call constructor without any parameter -> which means a call random Undead/Method from class Undeads
                break;
        }
    }


    public static T RandomEnumValue<T>()
    {
        var v = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
        return (T)v.GetValue(new Random().Next(v.Length));
    }

    public class Beasts : Enemy
    {
        public Beasts()
        {
            Beast choice = RandomEnumValue<Beast>();
            EnemySwitch(choice);
        }

        public Beasts(Beast beast)
        {
            EnemySwitch(beast);
        }

        private void EnemySwitch(Beast beast)
        {

            switch (beast)
            {
                case Beast.Bear:
                    Bear();
                    break;
                case Beast.Wolf:
                    Wolf();
                    break;
                case Beast.Boar:
                    Boar();
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void Bear()
        {
            HP = 120;
            Attack = 20;
            Defense = 15;
            Name = "Bear";
        }

        public void Boar()
        {
            HP = 100;
            Attack = 30;
            Defense = 10;
            Name = "Boar";
        }

        public void Wolf()
        {
            HP = 50;
            Attack = 35;
            Defense = 5;
            Name = "Wolf";
        }
    }

    public class Undeads : Enemy
    {
        public Undeads()
        {
            Undead choice = RandomEnumValue<Undead>();
            EnemySwitch(choice);
        }

        public Undeads(Undead undead)
        {
            EnemySwitch(undead);
        }

        private void EnemySwitch(Undead undead)
        {
            switch (undead)
            {
                case Undead.Skeleton:
                    Skeleton();
                    break;
                case Undead.Ghost:
                    Ghost();
                    break;
                case Undead.Ghoul:
                    Ghoul();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void Ghoul()
        {
            HP = 100;
            Attack = 30;
            Defense = 20;
            Name = "Ghoul";
        }

        private void Ghost()
        {
            HP = 100;
            Attack = 30;
            Defense = 20;
            Name = "Ghost";
        }

        private void Skeleton()
        {
            HP = 100;
            Attack = 30;
            Defense = 20;
            Name = "Skeleton";
        }
    }
```

Is there any way how to make it working that way? Or do I need to use any other solution?
I am new in OOP and it seems to me like a perfect way to use Bestiary exactly the way I am trying to use it. To derive specific groups and create methods for specific creatures, right?
The best would be probably some SQL database, but for the beginning and understanding OOP I want to go this way.

Thank you in advance for any help! Merry Christmas!

Comment: How is this question related to C++? It's all C#.

Comment: Because C++ programmers are more experienced in games and have some ideas how to do this proper and show me the way. So any advice from them would be great!

Comment: But I deleted tag C++ to satisfy you ;)

Comment: As an experienced C++ programmer and an inexperienced C# programmer, my great idea that I'd like to share is: "Please migrate your code to C++."

Comment: I wouldn't make these derived classes at all. I know everyone gives animals as an example of a class hierarchy but I think it's typically a poor example. In your case, the beast and undead classes don't add anything that you wouldn't get just by adding a monster type field to Enemy and flattening your class hierarchy.

Comment: But if I will have 50 creatures mixed as beasts, undeads, humanoids in base class Enemy and variables won't be only HP, Attack, Defense and Name, but e.g. 20 different variables, then the code will be really difficult and looong..?

Comment: I wouldn't do any of that in code at all.  That is data, and should be separated from code into either some kind of data file or database. I'd actually probably make two classes - BestiaryEntry which would query a localdb thorough Entity Framework, and Enemy whose constructor took a BestiaryEntry. The properties of both classes would be very similar but Enemy would lack the db access pieces. Then making a random enemy with certain constraints would just be a query for a random matching row in the bestiary.

Comment: Honestly thanks to Unity3d there probably more c# game developers than c++ game developers nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

In a language agnostic view of OOP here is what I think you should do:

1. break out all individual enemies into their own class, i.e. Bear, Boar, and Wolf should be individual classes and the same goes for all undead.

   ```
   public class Beast : Enemy    
   {
       public Beast(HP, Attack, Defense, Name) {
           this.HP = HP;
           this.Attack = Attack;
           this.Defense = Defense;
           this.Name = Name;
       }
   }

   public class Bear : Beast
   {
       public Bear() {
           Beast(120, 20, 15, "Bear");
       }
   }
   ```
2. All classes should be contained in their own file (usually).
3. Rather than calling a random class derived from enemy in the constructor, you want to use the Factory Pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) as another seperate class. e.g.

   ```
   public class EnemyFactory
   {
       public static Enemy getEnemy() {
           // Logic previously in Enemy() constructor
           return enemy;
       }
   }
   ```

(I don't know C# so the code might be off)

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful! I am trying to use that pattern from Wiki, which is pretty hard (because of interfaces, etc...), but I can learn it and use it!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know calling constructor of derived class through base class is not possible. Although you can call base constructor on derived class via base keyword. e.g.

```
public class Beasts
{
    public Beasts(int a) { }
}

public class Enemy : Beasts
{
    public Enemy() : base(5) { }
}
```